# Jetpack Compose - how to make SwipeToDismiss work on LazyRow?

Tags: android, listview, material-ui, android-jetpack-compose, swipe

I saw many examples about SwipeToDismiss working on LazyColumn but I did not see one implementing it on LazyRow. Here is my current implementation -

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardDataState(dashboardCardModels: List<DashboardCardModel>) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        backgroundStartColor,
                        backgroundEndColor
                    )
                )
            ),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {
            items(dashboardCardModels) { model ->
           
                val dismissState = rememberDismissState()

                when {
                    dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart) ->{

                    }
                    dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.StartToEnd) ->{

                    }
                }

                SwipeToDismiss(
                    state = rememberDismissState(),
                    background = {
                        val color by animateColorAsState(
                            when (dismissState.targetValue) {
                                DismissValue.Default -> Color.White
                                DismissValue.DismissedToEnd -> Color.Blue
                                DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> Color.Red
                            }
                        )
                        val alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
                        val icon = Icons.Default.Delete

                        val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                            if (dismissState.targetValue == DismissValue.Default) 0.75f else 1f
                        )

                        Box(
                            Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .background(color)
                                .padding(horizontal = Dp(20f)),
                            contentAlignment = alignment
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                icon,
                                contentDescription = "Delete Icon",
                                modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    dismissContent = {
                        DashboardCard(model = model)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What happens is that I am able to swipe the LazyRow horizontally, but obviously I want to swipe it vertically. How can I achieve such behavior?

Comment: I think its possible but maybe difficult, but considering the user's experience, isn't it a bit awkward for the users to have an X-Axis widget with an X-axis action on it?

Comment: @z.g.y I don't know if that was a typo but or not but what I want to achieve is an x-axis widget with a y-axis action on it, which is not weird. The current behavior is weird and is not what I want, which is an x-axis widget with an x-axis action

Answer (score 1):

Going deeper into the `SwipeToDismiss` code and learning it's behavior, I made some simple modifications, changing the `height` variable to `width`, the swipe orientation to `Orientation.Vertical` and the offset of the `dismissContent` variable to go on the y axis instead of the x axis. I named my modified composable `SwipeToDismissVertical` and it works perfectly

```kotlin
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterialApi
fun SwipeToDismissVertical(
    state: DismissState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    directions: Set<DismissDirection> = setOf(DismissDirection.EndToStart, DismissDirection.StartToEnd),
    dismissThresholds: (DismissDirection) -> ThresholdConfig = {
        FixedThreshold(DISMISS_THRESHOLD)
    },
    background: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit,
    dismissContent: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit
) = BoxWithConstraints(modifier) {
    val width = constraints.maxWidth.toFloat()
    val isRtl = LocalLayoutDirection.current == LayoutDirection.Rtl

    val anchors = mutableMapOf(0f to DismissValue.Default)
    if (DismissDirection.StartToEnd in directions) anchors += width to DismissValue.DismissedToEnd
    if (DismissDirection.EndToStart in directions) anchors += -width to DismissValue.DismissedToStart

    val thresholds = { from: DismissValue, to: DismissValue ->
        dismissThresholds(getDismissDirection(from, to)!!)
    }
    val minFactor =
        if (DismissDirection.EndToStart in directions) SwipeableDefaults.StandardResistanceFactor else SwipeableDefaults.StiffResistanceFactor
    val maxFactor =
        if (DismissDirection.StartToEnd in directions) SwipeableDefaults.StandardResistanceFactor else SwipeableDefaults.StiffResistanceFactor
    Box(
        Modifier.swipeable(
            state = state,
            anchors = anchors,
            thresholds = thresholds,
            orientation = Orientation.Vertical,
            enabled = state.currentValue == DismissValue.Default,
            reverseDirection = isRtl,
            resistance = ResistanceConfig(
                basis = width,
                factorAtMin = minFactor,
                factorAtMax = maxFactor
            )
        )
    ) {
        Row(
            content = background,
            modifier = Modifier.matchParentSize()
        )
        Row(
            content = dismissContent,
            modifier = Modifier.offset { IntOffset(0, state.offset.value.roundToInt(), ) }
        )
    }
}

private val DISMISS_THRESHOLD = 56.dp

private fun getDismissDirection(from: DismissValue, to: DismissValue): DismissDirection? {
    return when {
        // settled at the default state
        from == to && from == DismissValue.Default -> null
        // has been dismissed to the end
        from == to && from == DismissValue.DismissedToEnd -> DismissDirection.StartToEnd
        // has been dismissed to the start
        from == to && from == DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> DismissDirection.EndToStart
        // is currently being dismissed to the end
        from == DismissValue.Default && to == DismissValue.DismissedToEnd -> DismissDirection.StartToEnd
        // is currently being dismissed to the start
        from == DismissValue.Default && to == DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> DismissDirection.EndToStart
        // has been dismissed to the end but is now animated back to default
        from == DismissValue.DismissedToEnd && to == DismissValue.Default -> DismissDirection.StartToEnd
        // has been dismissed to the start but is now animated back to default
        from == DismissValue.DismissedToStart && to == DismissValue.Default -> DismissDirection.EndToStart
        else -> null
    }
}
```

The usage is exactly the same as before, but now I use my new composable instead of the material one -

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Composable
fun DashboardDataState(dashboardCardModels: List<DashboardCardModel>) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(
                brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(
                        backgroundStartColor,
                        backgroundEndColor
                    )
                )
            ),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
    ) {
        LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.wrapContentSize()) {
            items(dashboardCardModels) { model ->

                val dismissState = rememberDismissState()

                when {
                    dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.EndToStart) ->{

                    }
                    dismissState.isDismissed(DismissDirection.StartToEnd) ->{

                    }
                }

                SwipeToDismissVertical( //Here is the new one
                    state = dismissState,
                    background = {
                        val color by animateColorAsState(
                            when (dismissState.targetValue) {
                                DismissValue.Default -> Color.Transparent
                                DismissValue.DismissedToEnd -> Color.Blue
                                DismissValue.DismissedToStart -> Color.Red
                            }
                        )
                        val alignment = Alignment.CenterEnd
                        val icon = Icons.Default.Delete

                        val scale by animateFloatAsState(
                            if (dismissState.targetValue == DismissValue.Default) 0.75f else 1f
                        )

                        Box(
                            Modifier
                                .fillMaxSize()
                                .background(color)
                                .padding(horizontal = Dp(20f)),
                            contentAlignment = alignment
                        ) {
                            Icon(
                                icon,
                                contentDescription = "Delete Icon",
                                modifier = Modifier.scale(scale)
                            )
                        }
                    },
                    dismissContent = {
                        DashboardCard(model = model)
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```